# Add Days in Month in Calendar Pragmatically

Tags: android, calendar

I am creating calendar for my country where calendar is different. We have  31 days in February in our calendar and by default I am only getting 28 days. How  can I add 3 more days and make it up to 31?

```
  int  daysInMonth[]={31, 31, 31, 32, 31, 31, 30, 29, 30, 29, 30, 30}
  // I want to show calendar days up to 31 for jan, 31 for feb, 31 for march, 32 for April and show on.
 How can I achieve this?

 public void updateCalendar(HashSet<Date> events)
{
    ArrayList<Date> cells = new ArrayList<>();

    Calendar calendar = (Calendar)currentDate.clone();
    Log.d("myError1",""+calendar);

    // determine the cell for current month's beginning
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    int monthBeginningCell = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) - 1;
    Log.d("myError2",""+monthBeginningCell);

    // move calendar backwards to the beginning of the week
    calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, -monthBeginningCell);

    // fill cells
    while (cells.size() < DAYS_COUNT)
    {
        cells.add(calendar.getTime());
        //calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH,1);
        if (Calendar.MONTH==1){
            calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK,3);
        }
    }

    // update grid
    grid.setAdapter(new CalendarAdapter(getContext(), cells, events));

    // update title
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
    txtDate.setText(sdf.format(currentDate.getTime()));
```

Comment: You will have to create your custom calendar object. Standard Calendars won't allow you to do that. So you cant use standard methods like DAY of Month etc.

Comment: I am afraid there is no other way than writing your own class because all the calculation logic is based on that.

Comment: @kapsym Thanks  for the information

Comment: @Joshua Is it possible  on default calendar using logic or I have to create a custom Calendar  object  as mention by the  #kapsym ??

Comment: @AppleAppala You have to create a custom Calendar. What Calendar store is only millisecond. All other values is cached calculation result based on millisecond .

Comment: @Joshua ok Thank you. Can you provide me some documentation link if possible?

Comment: @AppleAppala There is no such documentation but you can take a look at the source code of openjdk. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Calendar.java

Comment: Which country have 31 days in February & 32 days in April??

Comment: @AshishJohn I am from Nepal and Nepali Calendar has 31 days in february and 32 days in April this year. The current year is 2074. You can take a look at this calendar https://www.nepalicalendar.com/